# How it works FileWatcher?

Tags: c#, hook, file-watcher, file-monitoring

Does anyone know to explain in detail and in-depth, how it works FileWatcher component?
As it receives events?
Through which channels travels signal change occurred?
Who initiates that signal?
As a signal change is registered in the FileWatcher?
Whether the component makes hooks the operating system?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396?

Comment: Feel free to investigate https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs,a9eb0249dc928b09 there are some unsafe winapi methods used like ReadDirectoryChangesW